# Why is a piece missing in an English translation of Herodotus Histories?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece

Original text from Herodotus "Histories" (Book One, chapter 203):

> ἡ δὲ Κασπίη θάλασσα ἐστὶ ἐπ᾽ ἑωυτῆς, οὐ συμμίσγουσα τῇ ἑτέρῃ θαλάσσῃ. τὴν μὲν γὰρ Ἕλληνὲς ναυτίλλονται πᾶσα καὶ ἡ ἔξω στηλέων θάλασσα ἡ Ἀτλαντὶς καλεομένη καὶ ἡ Ἐρυθρὴ μία ἐοῦσα τυγχάνει. ἡ δὲ Κασπίη ἐστὶ ἑτέρη ἐπ᾽ ἑωυτῆς, ἐοῦσα μῆκος μὲν πλόου εἰρεσίῃ χρεωμένῳ πεντεκαίδεκα ἡμερέων, εὖρος δέ, τῇ εὐρυτάτη ἐστὶ αὐτὴ ἑωυτῆς, ὀκτὼ ἡμερέων. καὶ τὰ μὲν πρὸς τὴν ἑσπέρην φέροντα τῆς θαλάσσης ταύτης ὁ Καύκασος παρατείνει, ἐὸν ὀρέων καὶ πλήθεϊ μέγιστον καὶ μεγάθεϊ ὑψηλότατον. ἔθνεα δὲ ἀνθρώπων πολλὰ καὶ παντοῖα ἐν ἑωυτῷ ἔχει ὁ Καύκασος, τὰ πολλὰ πάντα ἀπ᾽ ὕλης ἀγρίης ζώοντα:  ἐν τοῖσι καὶ δένδρεα φύλλα τοιῆσδε ἰδέης παρεχόμενα εἶναι λέγεται, τὰ τρίβοντάς τε καὶ παραμίσγοντας ὕδωρ ζῷα ἑωυτοῖσι ἐς τὴν ἐσθῆτα ἐγγράφειν: τὰ δὲ ζῷα οὐκ ἐκπλύνεσθαι, ἀλλὰ συγκαταγηράσκειν τῷ ἄλλῳ εἰρίῳ κατὰ περ ἐνυφανθέντα ἀρχήν. μῖξιν δὲ τούτων τῶν ἀνθρώπων εἶναι ἐμφανέα κατὰ περ τοῖσι προβάτοισι.

(see for example [here](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0125%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D203%3Asection%3D1))

I remember reading this passage in Russian, see for example [here](https://docviewer.yandex.com/view/0/?page=5&*=nhbInHKjsTFveb5ff9KmjHMXsLB7InVybCI6InlhLWRpc2stcHVibGljOi8veDBRNys1d0gzN05sMmZBYnJGZDRRdkNieDdxWEZlVUcxbmFnVDcxM3I2az0iLCJ0aXRsZSI6IjE5NzItbC1oZXJvZC5wZGYiLCJub2lmcmFtZSI6ZmFsc2UsInVpZCI6IjAiLCJ0cyI6MTY4NDYxMDMzNTMxMSwieXUiOiI3ODIzNzk1MTMxNjg0NjEwMzMyIn0%3D), and the literal translation from Russian of this chapter ends with something like

> μῖξιν δὲ τούτων τῶν ἀνθρώπων εἶναι ἐμφανέα κατὰ περ τοῖσι προβάτοισι.   (original)
>
> But the copulation of these people is evident, similar to that of sheep.   (Russian)

However, I could not find that in some English translations, for example, the 1910's translation by George Rawlinson ([here](https://files.romanroadsstatic.com/materials/herodotus.pdf)). However, some translations (see [this](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D203%3Asection%3D2) or [this](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2707/2707-h/2707-h.htm#link2H_4_0004) for example) do contain that phrase.

Is this some sort of censorship in the translation?

Comment: Thank you! I provided a link to a PDF which for the particular chapter seems consistent what I have in a printed copy.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, after doing some more research, it appears that some English translations are complete in that sense.

Comment: Here you have more examples of Rawlinson's censorship: reddit.com/r/books/comments/vfoi2r/herodotus_and_obscenity/&ved=2ahUKEwjA_Omk3oT_AhVThv0HHcqRDasQFnoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0uY370o9_q3ZXxgocWKJ2s